# Get Total SUM Result of 4 differents table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sum, calculator

I have 4 tables with same columns (`id` & `banka_id` & `miktar`).

2 tables earnings (`drink_earn`, `eat_earn` ) and

2 tables spending (`drink_spending`, `eat_spending` )

```
|id|banka_id|miktar|
---|--------|------|
|1 |2       |20    |
|2 |1       |20    |
|3 |1       |30    |
```

My question.

How can i calculate all of in one while row?

`drink_earn` : table SUM(miktar) is = 50$

`eat_earn` : table SUM(miktar) is = 50$

---

`drink_spending` : table SUM(miktar) is =  15$

`eat_spending` : table SUM(miktar) is =  5$

---

earnings: `drink_earn` + `eat_earn` = 100$

spending: `drink_spending` + `eat_spending` 20$

Total: earnnings - spending = 80$

and finally GROUP BY `banka_id`

Can you please write code sample. Regards.

Comment: how are you getting 50$ from the sample data you have given?

Comment: it is only example. i just show my table rows id, banka_id, miktar  in the drink_earn getting 50$ with SUM(miktar) understand?

Comment: you are right @Strawberry sorry for it. i fix it. and i made this and it works for me. is it true?
||| SELECT total.*, SUM(miktar) as miktartotal FROM ( SELECT * FROM drink_earn UNION ALL SELECT * FROM eat_earn UNION ALL SELECT * FROM eat_spending UNION ALL SELECT * FROM cekimler) AS total GROUP BY banka_id`|||

Comment: You're returning arbitrary ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine all tables into one with UNION ALL:

```
select banka_id, sum(earn) - sum(spend) as total
from (
    select banka_id, miktar as earn, 0 as spend
    from drink_earn
    union all
    select banka_id, miktar as earn, 0 as spend
    from eat_earn
    union all
    select banka_id, 0 as earn, miktar as spend
    from drink_spending
    union all
    select banka_id, 0 as earn, miktar as spend
    from eat_spending
) t
group by banka_id
```

But it would be better, if you had all the data in only one table with one additional column for type.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Spiegel its work. but this is work too ( SELECT total.*, 
       Sum(miktar) AS miktartotal 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   drink_earn 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   eat_earn 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   eat_spending 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   drink_spending) AS total 
GROUP  BY banka_id ` )    is it true?

Comment: @IsmailAltunören - The difference is that you are returning a sum of all earnings and spendings. But you need sum(earnings) - sum(spendings) like you wrote in your question.

Comment: Just asked if it true @Paul Spiegel. Thank you for your help.

Comment: i just want to ask you one more question @Paul  how can i include to spend + commission ? not with percent.  cross spend and commission like sum(spend+commission)